# How to resolve infinite recursion in __getattribute__ with class variables

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a base class which is inherited from by multiple classes. In the child classes, I want to make a method from the base class uncallable; so I'm using `__getattribute__` to raise an error if they are tried from the child class. Dummy example below:

```
class Base(object):
    def f1():
        return 1

    def f2():
        return 2

    def f3():
        return 3


class Child1(Base):
     def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'f1':
            raise AttributeError(name)
        else:
            return super(Child1, self).__getattribute__(name)


class Child2(Base):
     def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'f2':
            raise AttributeError(name)
        else:
            return super(Child2, self).__getattribute__(name)


class Child3(Base):
     def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'f3':
            raise AttributeError(name)
        else:
            return super(Child3, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

So in this example, I don't want to be able to call `f1` from `Child1`, `f2` from `Child2`, and `f3` from `Child3`.

Is there a way to re-write this that doesn't have so much code duplication and child classes just inherit the method? This is what I tried, but it first runs into recursion issues because the call to `self.blocked_methods` in and of itself calls `__getattribute__`. I imagine there are other issues but can't get past that one.

```
class Base(object):
    blocked_methods = []

    def f1():
        return 1

    def f2():
        return 2

    def f3():
        return 3

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in self.blocked_methods:
            raise AttributeError(name)
        else:
            return super(Child3, self).__getattribute__(name)


class Child1(Base):
     blocked_methods = ['f1']


class Child2(Base):
     blocked_methods = ['f2']


class Child3(Base):
     blocked_methods = ['f3']
```

Comment: "In certain classes, I want to make a method from the base class uncallable" You understand that this is explicitly the opposite of what inheritance is supposed to be for, yes?

Comment: This suggests that `Base` is not the appropriate base class for any of the three child classes. Consider defining separate mixin classes for each of the three methods instead.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I'll look into mixins for a better design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple mix-in classes instead.

```
class Method1:
    def f1(self):
        return 1

class Method2:
    def f2(self):
        return 2

class Method3:
    def f3(self):
        return 3

class Child1(Method2, Method3):
    pass

class Child2(Method1, Method3):
    pass

class Child1(Method2, Method2):
    pass
```

It's not terribly scalable, but it's better than trying to subtract functionality from a class.

Comment: This looks like the best approach for what I'm after, there would only be 3-4 mix-in classes. This actually works perfectly as now I can isolate and group functions specific to that mix-in.